# How to get Graph api key for age restricted page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the events from an 17+ facebook page. I do this in php and I want the feed, nothing complex.

I use the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/UID/events?access_token=1234|ABCD
```

Which results in:

```
"error": {
   "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 1
}
```

After a lot of digging I found that this vague message means (at least in my case), it's the age restriction. When I change it to 13+ (no restrictions), the url above works perfectly fine.

**All topics I find about this matters tell me to use a accesstoken from something old enough, how do I get that?**

I'm currently logged into an account who owns the facebookpage, and he's old enough (50+ yrs old).
I've changed settings of the app to alcohol page, and the same for the facebookpage itself (its a bar). No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and create a new User Access Token with the appropriate permissions. You're using an App Access Token currently, so this won't work with age restrictions afaik.

Comment: Perfect. Most things on FB are "Ah, gotcha", same goes for this. Switched back to 17+ with this token, working fine